# How do you InitializeCriticalSection in a reentrant manner?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I am modifying a library which is entirely reentrant to add windows support. The problem is the initialization function. The initialization function is wrapped in `MUTEX_LOCK(&ssl_lock);` and `MUTEX_UNLOCK(&ssl_lock);` in order to garuntee that everything is initalized only once.

The problem is that I cannot call `EnterCriticalSection` before `InitializeCriticalSection` and `InitializeCriticalSection` is not reentrant. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is writing documentation that says "It is undefined to call `mylib_init` more than once" a valid solution?

Comment: @TravisGockel the problem with that is that the init functions are called internally by the library so that no initialization is needed by the caller.

Comment: GCC has a cool thing called threadsafe-statics, but it doesn't look like MSVC has an equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what version sof Windows you need to support, you can use the "Init Once" APIs:

- [One-Time Initialization MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363808)
- [Patterns for using the InitOnce functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/08/10151258.aspx)

If you need to support WinXP/Win Server 2003 or older, you may need to rely on a Mutex object that the kernel can ensure only gets created once.  You'll need to implement some logic when opening/creating the mutex to make sure all threads of execution end up with a valid handle (ie., a loop that attempts to open, then attempts to create until the open or create succeeds).

Comment: Just as an aside, I did what you said, but in a completely different manner: I used `InterlockedExchange` to check an init variable, and depending on the result of that value i then called `InitializeCriticalSection`

Comment: @chacham15: that can guarantee that there will be only one call to `InitializeCriticalSection()`, but there's a danger with that method if it's possible for more than one thread to hit that code before `InitializeCriticalSection()` is called - only one thread will decide to call `InitializeCriticalSection()`, but the others will move on and possibly use the critical section object before it has been initialized.  You need to have a way to block those other threads until after the initialization call has completed (a busy wait loop on the atomic variable would probably do the trick).

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize it in your DllMain() DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH handler.

Comment: there is no dll main, it is a statically linked library